# Selector for a function with multiple parameters

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication

I need my app extension to open my host app with a parameter. I do so by opening a custom `URL` with `UIApplication.shared`.

Now. My last build has been rejected in test flight with a message `"Need test for export compliance"` or something like that (iTunes connect does not want to run in English). So I think that `Require only App-Extension-Safe API` set to `NO` in my extension's `Build Settings` is a possible reason of the problem.

Setting the flag to `YES` disables the use of `UIApplication.shared`. So I've decided to use the old way I found here some time ago (unfortunately, can't find the record):

```
// Get "UIApplication" class name through ASCII Character codes.
NSString *className = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:(unsigned char []){0x55, 0x49, 0x41, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E} length:13] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
if (NSClassFromString(className))
{
    //  A different way to call [UIApplication sharedApplication]
    id object = [NSClassFromString(className) performSelector: @selector(sharedApplication)];
    //  These lines invoke selector with 3 arguments
    SEL selector = @selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:);
    id  (*method)(id, SEL, id, id, id) = (void *)[object methodForSelector: selector];
    method(object, selector, myURL, nil, nil);
    //  Close extension
    [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems: @[] completionHandler: nil];
}
```

As you can see, this is `Objective-C`, but I also need to make it `Swifty`.
So here's where I'm stuck:

```
let codes = [CUnsignedChar](arrayLiteral: 0x55, 0x49, 0x41, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E)
let className = String(data: Data(bytes: UnsafeRawPointer(codes), count: 13), encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) ?? ""
if NSClassFromString(className) != nil
{
    let object = NSClassFromString(className)?.shared()
    let sel = #selector(_:options:completionHandler:)
    let meth = object?.method(for: sel)
    ...
```

The problem is with `sel` (expected expression). The method I am trying to reference here is

```
open(_:options:completionHandler:)
```

This thing

```
#selector(open(_:options:completionHandler:))
```

does not work either(use of unresolved identifier) since the view controller I am implementing this code in has no such method.

So the question is: how do I create a nameless selector reference with a few parameters to use later with my `meth` object? Thanks.

Comment: ...I don't think `meth` is a good name for a variable.

Comment: @the4kman I will restructure the text later on. The names of the variables do not matter if the code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NSSelectorFromString` method which allows you to declare `Selector` instances using a `String`.

I don't have the full source code but with a few adjustments, the following should work:

```
NSSelectorFromString("open(_:options:completionHandler:)")
```

More documentation on the method is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395294-nsselectorfromstring?language=objc).

Comment: Thanks. I have another problem now: `NSClassFromString(className)?.shared()` gives me an undesired class object since `UIApplication` has no method `shared()`, but a class var `shared`. Maybe you know how one can access an unknown class' variable?

Comment: how about `let object = (NSClassFromString(className) as? UIApplication)?.shared()` ?

Comment: `Static member 'shared' cannot be used on instance of type 'UIApplication'`

Comment: Anyway, you did answer the question. I am marking the answer as a correct one and asking another one about `shared`.